# rMap Serbia where to find?

Tags: r

Does anybody could help me where to download map of Serbia for `rMaps` and how to make a connection of some variable to municipalities at this map?

I have installed `rMaps`...

```
mtq <- st_read("C:/Users/vjovanovic/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/cartography/shape/martinique.shp")
plot(st_geometry(mtq))
propSymbolsLayer(x = mtq, var = "P13_POP", legend.title.txt = "Population", col = "#a7dfb4")

srb <- st_read("C:/Users/vjovanovic/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/cartography/shape/rs_10km.shp")
plot(st_geometry(srb))
```

Comment: The last [commit to `rMaps` was in February 2016](https://github.com/ramnathv/rMaps/commits/master). I'd try to use something else instead, depending on your specific use case.

Answer (score 1):

https://gadm.org/ 
You can download the maps here according to **nuts**. I advice you to use **sp** package R . Download the sp file of the map data which level you want. Then you can read it with .

```
 serbia<-readRDS(" your path of the map file here") .
```

This is a special class of a data called spatialpolygonsdata frame of sp package. This data have slots.You can see the slot names with.

```
slotNames(serbia)
```

you can add the data you want acccording to ids. Here is an example.
https://rpubs.com/BeccaStubbs/bringing_shapefiles_into_R